# Knockout binding custom components to not conflict with central view model

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, ecmascript-6, babeljs, knockout-2.0

I am trying to create an application with custom components that interact with central service providers, which works fine.

You can see an example at https://github.com/brianlmerritt/knockout-babel-browserify-gulp

It's written in ES2015, and compiles fine.

The problem is that I want to be able to load a central view model that applies to each page except of course to the component which has it's own view models.

I thought I understood http://www.knockmeout.net/2012/05/quick-tip-skip-binding.html but when I surround the component with `<!-- ko stopBinding : true -->` the component fails to bind.  If I don't surround the component then I get a binding conflict.

If someone can point me to how to register a component in a way that the central view model doesn't conflict I would be very grateful!

Each custom component is registered with:

```
ko.components.register(
    'component-one', 
    require('./components/component-one/component.js'));
```

To keep the central view model simple, I just went with:

```
var centralViewModel = function centralViewModel() 
    { var bindingWorked = ko.observable(
        'The binding worked. KO view model centralViewModel has a this context and was bound to the html correctly');
};
```

Sadly when I do the bindings they conflict:

```
ko.applyBindings(centralViewModel(),document.body);
ko.applyBindings(); // Pull in all of the components
```

I am sure there must be a way to pull in the components in a way that does not conflict with the central view model.

Comment: Why doesn't the first `applyBindings` pull in all the components?

Comment: It does, but the bindings conflict.  I need a way to tell centralViewModel not to overstep it's mark and leave the components alone

Comment: Hi @RoyJ - the problem wasn't a conflict between the central and component viewmodels - it was with the code in centralViewModel

Answer (score 0):

It seems the conflict was actually averted correctly by applying centralViewModel to the DOM. There was no conflict with the components. The problem was in the centralViewModel.

Corrected code:

```
ko.components.register(
    'component-one',
    require('./components/component-one/component.js')
);

ko.components.register(
    'component-two',
    require('./components/component-two/component.js')
);

ko.components.register(
    'component-three',
    require('./components/component-three/component.js')
);
var centralViewModel = {
    bindingWorked : ko.observable('The binding worked. KO view model centralViewModel has a this context and was bound to the html correctly')
};

ko.applyBindings(centralViewModel,document.body);
```